# Logo not display in spree commerce

Tags: spree

I installed ROR and SPREE  in windows. When I am running the site, logo not displaying in the demo content.

Please tell the solution to fix it. I tried to change the logo using `spree.rb` with below code:

```
# Example:
# Uncomment to stop tracking inventory levels in the application
# config.track_inventory_levels = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this. may be it is helpful to you:

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.admin_interface_logo = 'logo/some_other_logo.png'
  config.logo = 'logo/this_logo.png'
end
```